# How to solve w3 validation error bad value?

Tags: html, url, w3c-validation, url-parsing

The W3C validation report me this error:

> Error: Bad value
>   //fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700|PT+Serif:400,700 for
>   attribute href on element link: Illegal character in query: | is not
>   allowed. From line 58, column 1; to line 58, column 163
>   ='all' />↩

How I must solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can encode that character to make this valid:

```
//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700%7CPT+Serif:400,700
```

This should then be a valid value.